# Could you convert dynamic pdf files to static pdf files using iTEXT?

Tags: java, pdf, dynamic, static, itext

I'm created dynamic PDF templates using adobe livecycle designer, and using ITEX to fill the templates with XML data, and generated final PDF document.

Now the final PDF document still dynamic. So then Can't showing Binding Data of PDF Viewer.
I hope to convert dynamic to static document using itext..

etc.
I have tested by open the dynamic document, select file ->print setup->printer(adobe PDF) to print a new PDF file, by that way, the PDF type is static

```
        [Sum up Sample]
        public void manipulatePdf(InputStream is , String src, String dest, String path)throws IOException, DocumentException {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is); //to read dynamic pdf file
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(dest));

        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();

        xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream( path + "/pdf-temp-file/Data.xml" ) ,true);
        xfa.setXfaPresent(false);

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
}'
```

How cloud i use something API or set configuration?? help me..

Comment: I guess the [XFA Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xfa_worker) is what you are searching for?

Comment: I refer their site. so then i use method like manipulatePdf( ... ). but i think it is all dynamic pdf files